# Super Robot Wars X - Any way to load a save file saved in another language?

Tags: steam, super-robot-wars

I started Super Robot Wars X in a translated language, but since now I'm preparing for the Japanese N2 exam, I want to finish the game in Japanese (the conversations are not very complicated). Some original subtleties could also be lost in translation.

However, if I change the language and launch the game again, when I try to load the previous save files, the game just doesn't do anything and starts itself from the starting screen again. The same happens if I try to load the save file saved in Japanese with a different UI. Surely there must be a way to make the save files compatible with each other? I tried to look into the DESC.BIN and SYSTEM.BIN but I need to find which bytes exactly to modify. Hope this question is not out of scope here. If anybody has some clue it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you changing the language in a game setting or a Steam setting?

Comment: @Wrigglenite It's a Steam setting for the game, though I think what it does is to simply toggle a flag in a configuration file. No new assets need to be downloaded whatsoever.

Comment: @Wrigglenite The game still sees the save file and even recognizes the stage, accumulated points, etc. etc. It just doesn't load it.